# AngularJS Routing isn't working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-routing

I'm new to angular. I'm trying to do routing. I wrote code as below

```js
 var mainApp = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute']);

 mainApp.config(
   function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
     when('/sampleOne', {
       templateUrl: 'SampleOne.html',
       controller: 'productController'
     }).
     when('/sampleTwo', {
       templateUrl: 'SampleTwo.html',
       controller: 'studentController'
     }).
     otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/'
     });
   });

 mainApp.controller('productController', function($scope) {
  //controller logic
 });

 mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
  //controller logic
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="MainApp">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#/sampleOne">Sample 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/sampleTwo">Sample 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

the code in two views is working fine.

When I run and click on links URL is changing but the content is not rendering, It is throwing a console error as below

```
  angular.js:13424 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: SampleTwo.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/tpload?p0=SampleTwo.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:18774)
    at processQueue (angular.js:15757)
    at angular.js:15773
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17025)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16841)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17133)
    at done (angular.js:11454)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11652)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:11593)
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your SampleTwo.html is?
in this case the templete file should in the same place where the controller script is placed.

Comment: It's my mistake only. I rectified by creating templates on the same page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

searched your error in [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=MainApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.23%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.23%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A494%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A502%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A267%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A284%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.23%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:34:97%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:33:284%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:33:207)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:36:309)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js:18:170):

> In AngularJS 1.2.0 and later, ngRoute has been moved to its own
>   module. If you are getting this error after upgrading to 1.2.x or
>   later, be sure that you've installed ngRoute.